# Drag and sort Listview OnItemClick issues android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-listview

I am using Drag and sort listview where I want to click an item,but problem is that when I sort the item, the position gets changed.How to solve this issue.I used this example. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist. My coding are as follows:

Java Class Using `DragNDropListView`

```
ListView listView = getListView();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);



    if (listView instanceof DragNDropListView) {
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setDropListener(mDropListener);
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setRemoveListener(mRemoveListener);
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setDragListener(mDragListener);

    }
}

private DropListener mDropListener = 
    new DropListener() {
    public void onDrop(int from, int to) {
        ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof DragNDropAdapter) {
            ((DragNDropAdapter)adapter).onDrop(from, to);
            getListView().invalidateViews();
        }
    }
};

private RemoveListener mRemoveListener =
    new RemoveListener() {
    public void onRemove(int which) {
        ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof DragNDropAdapter) {
            ((DragNDropAdapter)adapter).onRemove(which);
            getListView().invalidateViews();
        }
    }
};

private DragListener mDragListener =
    new DragListener() {

    int backgroundColor = 0xe0103010;
    int defaultBackgroundColor;

        public void onDrag(int x, int y, ListView listView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStartDrag(View itemView) {
            itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            defaultBackgroundColor = itemView.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            if (iv != null) iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onStopDrag(View itemView) {
            itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(defaultBackgroundColor);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            if (iv != null) iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

};

private static String[] mListContent={"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(position==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected item 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
    }

    if(position==1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
    }

    if(position==2)
    {
    Intent i=new Intent(a.this,b.class);
           startActivity(i);
    }
```

But when sorting, surely the position varies, so i couldnt use intent to pass to next

activity.How to rectify this in drag and sort listview?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where and when your are sorting ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the position in DropListener like this:

```
private int position = 0;

private DropListener mDropListener = new DropListener() {
            public void onDrop(int from, int to) {
                ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();
                if (adapter instanceof DragNDropAdapter) {
                    ((DragNDropAdapter) adapter).onDrop(from, to);
                    listView.invalidateViews();
                    if(position == from)
                        position = to;
                    else if(position == to && ((from - to) == 1 || (to - from) == 1))
                        position = from;
                    else if(position == to && (from - to) > 1)
                        position = (from - to)-1;
                    else if(position == to && (to - from) > 1)
                        position = (to - from)-1;
                    else if(position > from && position < to)
                        position -= 1;
                    else if(position < from && position >to)
                        position += 1;

                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can you tell me what & where is the issue ?

Comment: As u said, i have added this in DropListener and run it.But still i have issue.Want to do any change in OnItemClickListener? Because i am using listview.setOnItemClickListener(this); so it overrides the AdapterView.My doubt is, that position will check the DropListener? So only i think i am facing the issue.

Comment: First tell me the items are visible in the listview or you are having problem in adding items to it ?

Comment: Items are visible in listview dude.When i click it, it displays toast message of corresponding item.But when i sort and click it, it mismatches.

Comment: You are picking your items from database ?